# .net Capture real time GPS data

Tags: wpf, gps, streaming

I am wanting to build a car dashboard equivalent in C# WPF and I have everything running well with dummy data. I can find very little information on streaming live data from a GPS. Does anyone have experience with something like this and can you point me in the right direction.

Cheers

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these links to parse GPS data which you are getting from your GPS Device.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/jperson2000/writing-your-own-gps-applications-part-i/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/jperson2000/writing-your-own-gps-applications-part-ii/